# Windows form only executs when I press the buttons with the mouse

Tags: c#, winforms, debugging

I m working at an uni project and I encountered a problem.(I m also a beginner with C#). 
I created a windows form menu and I have to choose options via keyboard. But my program won't let me choose unless i clicked on the option prior. (I have to click the option then press the key, otherwise I can even spam the key and nothing will happen).

```
private void button1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if( e.KeyCode==Keys.D1 || e.KeyCode==Keys.NumPad1)
        {
            SidePanel.Height = button1.Height;
            SidePanel.Top = button1.Top;
            firstCustomControl1.BringToFront();
        }
    }
```

Here's a code snippet of how i choose an option based on the number.
Thank you :)

Comment: on form load  button1.Focus(); If you want that global - make sure that key down event is on form (parent) and not button - otherwise key down will not be triggered before you select the button.

Comment: Do you define menu shortcuts and they don't work until you click on form (or on control of the form)? Could be indeed problem with keyboard focus.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly Set "KeyPreview" Option of your form on which you tend to perform action to true, it is false by default. It needs to be true to perform any function based on any keyboard event.

Secondly add Keydown  event on same form.

```
   private void YourForm_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
   {
      YourCodeHere();
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

don't use the Keydown event on your Button!
Select the Form in the designer and add Keydown Event for entire Form.

[Add Key Down Event on Form 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eR41M.jpg)

then add your Code to the following auto generated Method

```
private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    YourCodeHere();
}
```